# Spring - "late binding" autowired beans

Tags: java, hibernate, spring, dependency-injection

Let's say I have the following dependencies:

```
@Configuration
public class MyCfg {
  // ...
  @Bean
  public Session session() {
    return sessionFactory().getCurrentSession();
  }
}

@Repository
@Transactional
public class MyRepo {
  @Autowired
  private Session session;
}
```

`sessionFactory()` is set up properly. If I inject `SessionFactory` instead of `Session`, it works just fine. However, if try and inject `Session`, it dies with an exception on container bootstrap because there is no session bound to thread.

Since the repository is `@Transactional`, I know that at run time there will be a session. How can I make it work, so that it injects AOP-initialized `Session` at run time, but does not try and resolve it when the repo is instantiated?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This approach will get you into a lot of trouble. Instead of injecting a `Session`, which you now automatically scopes as a singleton, you should inject the `SessionFactory` instead. Instances of `Session` acquired within a `@Transactional` annotated method will adhere to those transaction rules, eg:

```
@Transactional(readonly=true)
public List<Person> getPersons() {
  Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
  //find those darn people.
}
@Autowired
private SessionFactory sessionFactory;
```

Comment: I know how to do that, and that's exactly what I'm trying to avoid. I don't want so many factories and boilerplate floating around.

Answer (score 2):

I would take a look at this bit of [Spring documentation regarding bean scopes](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/reference/beans.html#beans-factory-scopes).  Near the bottom they show how to use the `@Scope` annotation, which you will want to apply to your `session()` method in `MyCfg`.  It sounds like you would want to use the 'request' value, which will create a new instance of this bean for each HTTP request coming in.

I will also suggest taking a look at the `<aop:scoped-proxy/>` element for configuration.  It is mentioned a couple times in the documentation, and may be useful for what you are trying to do.

Comment: What if I have more than one transaction per request?

Comment: I am not entirely sure, but you may need to build a custom scope in this case.  Look at section 3.5.5 in the documentation for how to create a custom 'transaction' scope.